React Signals does not render while UseState does
I have build my first React try-out app using UseState and am now trying to switch to React Signals in that same try-out app. Everything seems to work, I get no errors and the browser console shows data is returned, this holds true for the UseState based data as well as the UseSignals based data. However, the UseSignals based data will not render in My app. I am a novice so am probably making a beginners mistake, but I do not seem to be able to figure out what mistake. Assistance in solving this would be much appreciated!
Here's the code, please do not mind the general clumsiness of it, focus on the Signals topic is key for now.
import { useState } from 'react';
**import { useSignal } from '@preact/signals-react'**

const FamiliezSysteem = () => {

    const MWDtFeReq = **useSignal("");**
    const MWDtMwReq = **useSignal("");**

    const handleButtonClickToPingMW = async () => {
        try {
            const now = new Date();
            const offset = now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; 
            const localISOTime = new Date(now - offset).toISOString().slice(0, -1); 
            
            const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/pingAPI?timestampFE=${localISOTime}`;

            const response = await fetch(url);
            const data = await response.json();
            MWDtFeReq.value = await data[0]["FE request time"];
            MWDtMwReq.value = await data[0]["MW request time"];
 
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Familiez systeem, FTW!</div>
            <button onClick={handleButtonClickToPingMW}>Ping MiddleWare</button>
            <pre> Frontend request Time= {MWDtFeReq.value} </pre>
            <pre> Middleware request Time= {MWDtMwReq.value} </pre>
        </div>

    );
};

export default FamiliezSysteem;

CoPilot gives me suggestions that are obvious not correct or seems correct but just do not work. So much for CoPilot in this case :-). So I searched the old fashioned way scowering the Internet but that did not bring ant solutions too. I started with a JSON object contained in an array (as still is the case for the data I fetch form the Database), then switched to a field per value approach (for the data I fetch from the Middleware only) without any containing structure. That did not make any difference. Then I switched the UseSignals statement arround, that did not help too. At this point in my learning curve I seem to be out of any further options, so I hope somebody can point me in the right direction.
PS: In the "Review questions already on Stack Overflow to see...." the last issue seems very much the same as mine. But that dev did not use Bable or UseSignal which seemed to be the problem in that case, wehere I do use UseSignal.

You've pasted so much code there that the issue is rather unclear, however, useSignals() should be the first thing in your component and you should not use signal() inside of one -- if you need to create a signal inside of a component, you must use useSignal() instead.

I condensed the code to what does not work, hope that make matters more clear. The changes you mentioned (I hope I understood them) still do not work. Valus are passed from my middleware code to the app and shown in the browser console, but still not rendered in the app itself. Hope somebody can give some further assistance. I am stuck on this and its driving me mad. So any further help would be very much appreciated!

Whoops, I just notices something else: My app also contains an element inside the component which uses useState. When I first use the useSignal based element nothing  renders, but when I, after that, use the useState element it renders the values it should but at that point also the useSignals values are rendered in the app. Meaning the values are all there, but useSignal on itself just does not seem to render the values. Still do not understand why useSignal in this code does not render.

useSignals(), plural. It's not the same thing as useSignal(). You need to use it, or the Babel plugin. Instructions

You need to use either useSignals() or the Babel plugin w/ React. Else, the component will not react to signal updates. Instructions.
 import { useSignal } from '@preact/signals-react'
+import { useSignals } from "@preact/signals-react/runtime";

 const FamiliezSysteem = () => {
+    useSignals();
 ...

It needs to be called first-thing each of your components that use signals.

That did the trick, very helpful. Thanks man! I saw the instructions you send the link for before. But I must have messed-up somewhere using that the first time, anyhow, not it works. Much appreciated!
